# What is wrong with Grunt's simple example file from official site?

Tags: gruntjs

I tried to set up grandfile.js, did it under http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks and https://24ways.org/2013/grunt-is-not-weird-and-hard/ . So I wrote there:

```
 module.exports = function(grunt) {

    // 1. All configuration goes here 
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        concat: {
            // 2. Configuration for concatinating files goes here.
    dist: {
        src: [
            'css/bootstrap.css', // Bootstrap css in the libs folder
        'css/normalize.css', // Normaliza.css in the libs folder
            'css/style.css'  // This specific file
        ],
        dest: 'css/build/production.css',
        }

    });

    // 3. Where we tell Grunt we plan to use this plug-in.
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');

    // 4. Where we tell Grunt what to do when we type "grunt" into the terminal.
    grunt.registerTask('concat');   
};
```

Then I opened Teminal and wrote `grunt`.
Here what I got:

```
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>> SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

I've not find any extra ) neither I create bad "default" task (default=concat).

What is wrong here?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Grunt expects you to register a default task (`grunt.registerTask('default', [<task list here>]`), but you do not *have* to.  If you don't wish to register it, then just pass the `--force` option like it mentions, and it should still run your task(s)

Comment: It doesn't work. After I do this my production.css file is still empty. Terminal says next: Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>> SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
Warning: Task "default" not found. Used --force, continuing.

Done, but with warnings.